# Movie about a guy living secretly in a family's attic who tries to kill them

Tags: identify-this-movie

This movie is similar to ***Hider in the House***. It's from maybe the early 90s or late 80s.

A boy and girl live with their father. In a house they just moved into. The girl and her friend were laying out in their bathing suits and her little brother sprays them with water. Then the girl has a 16th b'day party and her boyfriend is found dead outside the next day. Also her mom is in a nuthouse.

When a friend of her moms is released he was told by the mom to go and keep and eye on her kids. The guy does odds and ends on the house but secretly is living in the attic. Near the end of the movie the crazy guy nails all the doors and windows shut. I think he tries to kill the boy and girl but the father breaks through the front door and fights with the guy. At the bottom of the steps by the front door I believe the crazy guy is pushed down this hole he made with spikes at the bottom and dies. That's all I can remember.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like [Christina's House](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0216620/combined), though the year is a bit off (it's from 1999\2000).

> The teenager Christina, her younger brother Bobby, and their father James Tarling [John Savage] moves to a rented house in a small town in Washington to be close to Christina's mother Joanne, who is interned in an asylum. The house is being repaired by Howie Rhodes and Christina has a boyfriend, the bad boy Eddy Duncan. While in the house, Christina hears noises and has a permanent feeling that another person lives there, but her father believes it is the structure being settled.

It turns out that Howie the handyman was sent there by the mother to watch over the kids and that he lives in the attic and has set up booby traps like the one you described around the house. The trailer: